# Run multiple request at a time and continue as soon there is success

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

Given an array of urls, is there a way to run those at once simultaneously? But in such a way so as soon as there is one success move to the next request using that successful url.

So far I tried chaining `concatMap`, and failed with `zip`.

```
func updateAccountInfo() -> Single<Bool> {
    
    var disposable: Disposable? = nil
    
    return Single<Bool>.create { observer in
      
      do {
        
        var urls = try self.settings.domains.value()
        
        disposable = Observable.from(urls)
          .enumerated()
          .concatMap { index, url -> Single<URL> in
            return self.verifyUrl(url)
          }
          .concatMap { url -> Single<Account> in
            return self.apiManager.loadAccountInfo(from: url)
          }
          .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
          .do(onNext: { (account: AccountInfo) in
            // use account unfo here
            disposable!.dispose()
          })
          .subscribe()
        
      } catch {
        observer(.error(error))
      }
      
      return Disposables.create()
    }
  }
```

Tried like so too:

```
disposable = Observable.from(urls)
          .enumerated()
          .concatMap { index, url -> Single<(Bool, URL)> in
            return self.verifyUrl(url)
          }
          .subscribe(onNext: { reachable, url in
            if reachable {

              self.apiManager.loadAccountInfo(from: url)
                .subscribe(onSuccess: { accountInfo in
                  
                  // use account info here

                }, onError: { error in
                  
                })
                .disposed(by: self.bag)

              disposable!.dispose()
            } else {
              
            }
          }, onError: { error in
            
          }, onCompleted: {
          
          })
```

Maybe I use zip but how would I create an array of `verifyUrl(url)` calls? Does `zip` accept arrays of `Observable` at all?

```
let obs = Observable.from(urls)
          .enumerated()
          .concatMap { index, url -> Single<URL> in
            return self.verifyUrl(url)
          }
        
        let test = Observable
        .zip(obs).map { [urls] in 
          return [urls]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
func example() throws {
    let urls = try self.settings.domains.value()
    Observable.merge(urls.map { verifyUrl($0).asObservable() })
        .flatMap { [apiManager] url in
            apiManager!.loadAccountInfo(from: url)
        }
        .observe(on: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { account in
            // use account unfo here
        })
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}
```

But it's hard to tell. Your code samples are a bit jumbled. Putting all your code in a Single.create is odd. Returning a Disposables.create() from the closure when you have a disposable to return is odd. Calling dispose() on a disposable inside the do block is odd. So much weirdness... I suggest you post some code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com or look at sample code.

Comment: yeah, well, because it's odd to me, I'm trying to learn RxSwift but getting stuck confused about what to use where :) any tips or resources to get to that point of understanding where to put `.asObservable()` or `do` instead of `subscribe`?

Comment: your code looks so much cleaner! thank you a lot! I'll check `.merge` thingy

Comment: Use `subscribe` 99% of the time. I think in the past 6 years, I have only used `do` maybe 10 times. Use `asObservable()` only when the compiler complains that the types don't match and using it will make the types match. Come on over to the RxSwift slack. You will get a lot of help there. (https://rxslack.herokuapp.com)

Comment: I put everything into `Single.create` so I can subscribe to that function and `disposable!.dispose()` tried to use so chain is stopped when reachable url was used